# y code doesnt highlight paperscript part of code...it includes html.plist instead of html.json

Tags: html, json, plist

my code doesn't highlight paper script part of code...
I changed my HTML.plist also
from...

```
<key>begin</key>
        <string>(?:^\s+)?(&lt;)((?i:script))\b(?![^&gt;]*/&gt;)(?![^&gt;]*(?i:type.?=.? 
                  text/((?!javascript).*)))
        </string>enter code here
```

beginCaptures

to...

```
<key>begin</key>
        <string>(?:^\s+)?(&lt;)((?i:script))\b(?![^&gt;]*/&gt;)(?![^&gt;]*(?i:type.?=.? 
        text/((?!javascript).*)))</string>
        <string>(?:^\s+)?(&lt;)((?i:script))\b(?![^&gt;]*/&gt;)(?![^&gt;]*(?i:type.?=.? 
        text/((?!paperscript).*)))</string>
```

beginCaptures

but it still not works

as it has HTML.pl instead of html.json